# SizeChangedEventArgs could not be found are you missing a using directive

Tags: c#, forms

i am not able to figure this error out:
"SizeChangedEventArgs could not be found are you missing a using directive..."

Here my setup and code:

- using visual studio 2019
- Csharp
- Build .Net Framework 4.8
- using System.Windows

  ```
   private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the old size from the event arguments
        var newSize = ((Form)sender).Size;
        var oldWidth = e.PreviousSize.Width;
        var oldHeight = e.PreviousSize.Height;
        var oldSize = new Size(oldWidth, oldHeight);

        // Do something with the old size
        Console.WriteLine("Old size: {0}", oldSize);
    }
  ```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the correct parameter data type: `private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`. See [Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). Ultimately, if you follow the inheritance, you'll find that documentation for [SizeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: @user09938 It's [FrameworkElement.SizeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged?view=netframework-4.8) event. Not WinForm's.

Comment: @dr.null: Nowhere in the post does the poster mention `PresentationFramework` nor did the OP mention `WPF` I actually created a new WinForms project and added the `SizeChanged` event. The result is in my previous comment. If one creates a new `WPF App (.NET Framework)` and adds the `SizeChanged` event, then one sees `private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)`.  Furthermore, the codeblock shows `Form1_SizeChanged` which is the format of the method name in WinForms.

Comment: Right. Something fishy here. Perhaps the OP is trying to implement an event that belongs to different project's type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WinForms, the `SizeChanged` event gets written like this on my system:

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your responses, it seems i have to go educate myself about forms...So i am using winforms but not WPF.. from what i gathered from initial reading.

below is just for the record on how i solved my immediate problem.

-Calling the form:

```
assignForm myassignForm = new assignForm(List1_lst, List2_lst);
```

- Form Class:

  ```
    public partial class assignForm : Form
    {
     private Size client_old_sz = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 900);
     double ratioWidth = 1.0;
     double ratioHeight = 1.0;
  ```
- Form Resize handler declaration:

  ```
    private void InitializeComponent(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
      {
     this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load); 
     this.Resize += new EventHandler(Form1_Resize);
  ```
- Resize Event handlers definition:

  ```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client_old_sz = this.Size; // store the initial size of the form
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // calculate the ratio of the new size to the old size
         this.ratioWidth = (double)this.Size.Width / client_old_sz.Width;
         this.ratioHeight = (double)this.Size.Height / client_old_sz.Height;

        // store the new size as the old size for the next resize event
        client_old_sz = this.Size;
    }
  ```